# Logback JaninoEventEvaluator to direct log events to a specific appender

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I have a logback-test xml as follows. I wanted to filter out any logs from package org.jdbcds from console and from GENERIC_LOG_FILE and have them in a seperate file under appender SQLFILE. But neither of them works. All the logs from org.jdbcdslog logged in console and in GENERIC_LOG_FILE, but not under the file given in appender SQLFILE. Please help.

```
  <configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
           <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
          <evaluator>
              <expression>return logger.startsWith("org.jdbcdslog")</expression>
           </evaluator>
          <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
          <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="GENERAL_LOG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
          <append>true</append>
           <encoder>
                <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
           </encoder>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
                <evaluator>
                    <expression>return logger.startsWith("org.jdbcdslog")</expression>
                </evaluator>
                <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
                <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
            </filter>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/server.abacus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
                <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
            </rollingPolicy>
   </appender>
   <appender name="SQLFILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <!--<filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>message.contains("TestFinished()")</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>-->
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator> 
                <expression>return logger.startsWith("org.jdbcdslog");</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/all_query.abacus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.SlowQueryLogger" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger" level="INFO"/>
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
      <appender-ref ref="GENERAL_LOG_FILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="PERF_LOG_FILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="SQLFILE" />
      <appender-ref ref="SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE" />
   </root>
```

Update 1:

Here is the modified XML

```
<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="GENERAL_LOG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>message.contains("TestFinished()")</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>return logger.startsWith("Perf");</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>ACCEPT</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/server.abacus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ERROR_LOG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>message.contains("TestFinished()")</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/server.abacus.error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="PERF_LOG_FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>message.contains("TestFinished()")</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator> 
                <expression>return logger.startsWith("Perf");</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/perf.abacus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SQLFILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/all_query.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/slow_query.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="ab.xyz" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="bd.xyz" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="net.sf.hibernate" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="Perf" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.SlowQueryLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SQLFILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.ConnectionLogger" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLogger" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="GENERAL_LOG_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="PERF_LOG_FILE" />
    </root>


</configuration>
```

Update 2:

```
<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="GENERAL_LOG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>message.contains("TestFinished()")</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>return logger.startsWith("Perf");</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>ACCEPT</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/server.abacus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ERROR_LOG_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>message.contains("TestFinished()")</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/server.abacus.error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="PERF_LOG_FILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>message.contains("TestFinished()")</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>DENY</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>NEUTRAL</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator> 
                <expression>return logger.startsWith("Perf");</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <OnMatch>ACCEPT</OnMatch>
            <OnMismatch>DENY</OnMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/perf.abacus.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SQLFILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/all_query.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <appender name="SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}|%level|%logger|%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${user.home}/slow_query.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>14</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>
    <logger name="ab.xyz" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="cd.xyz" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="net.sf.hibernate" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="jdbc.sqlonly" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="Perf" level="INFO" />
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.SlowQueryLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="SQLFILE" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.ConnectionLogger" level="ERROR"/>
    <logger name="org.jdbcdslog.ResultSetLogger" level="ERROR"/>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="GENERAL_LOG_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR_LOG_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="PERF_LOG_FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="SQLFILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this:

> I wanted to filter out any logs from package org.jdbcds from console and from GENERIC_LOG_FILE and have them in a seperate file under appender SQLFILE

I don't think you *need* to use Janino, you can instead associate the `org.jdbcds` logger with the `SQLFILE` appender and use `additivity=false` to prevent this logger from being forwarded to other appenders.

For example:

```
<!-- direct logging from org.jdbcds to the SQLFILE appender and _only_ to the SQLFILE appender -->
<logger name="org.jdbcds" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="SQLFILE" />
</logger>
```

Comment: Hi @glytching, Thanks for the reply. I've modified the XML  as you suggested and posted the complete XML in my updated question. Though the org.jdbcdslog package logs are not logged in console any more, but still the said package logs are not logged under the files that I expected (all_query.log and slow_query.log). Please advice

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you last comment but looking at what you have posted I can see far more is going on there than simply using the logger-to-appender configuration. For example, there is also filtering based on `message.contains("TestFinished()")`. I'd suggest simplifying things and then building back up to the current level of complexity gradually. So, start with a simple logback.xml - with no Janino - but using the approach I described to direct `org.jdbcdslog.SlowQueryLogger` to `SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE` and once that's proven than add in one Janino  filter and iterate like that.

Comment: Except SQLFILE and SLOWQUERY_SQL appenders, the rest of the appenders are already exists and working fine. I just added the two appenders which I just mentioned.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what's happening **after** you made these changes. Are log events from `org.jdbcdslog.StatementLogger` and `org.jdbcdslog.SlowQueryLogger` written anywhere? Is it the case that they no longer appear in console or in the other file appenders but neither do they appear in `SLOWQUERY_SQLFILE` or `SQLFILE`?

Comment: Thanks glytching. Becuase I've removed my appenders from the root-logger, it didn't logged anywhere. Now I added them back in, and worked like charm. Updated the working xml in update 2 section of the question. Accepting your's as answer. Thanks once again.